# How to find sent emails in Outlook 2010 without a reply

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Here is an interesting question: In Outlook 2010, how could I find emails I sent that did not receive a reply? I'm open to almost all solutions.

Comment: I've pondered this myself on earlier versions of Outlook and the best I could come up with was a macro that would append a tracking code to the bottom of the email sent - ideally white text on a white background. You could then look for that code in any incoming messages to determine whether or not the message was replied to. It's pretty hacky though.

Comment: Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/970558/how-to-search-for-unanswered-emails

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure this out just now. On the sent folder, I changed the settings so that messages would show as conversations. This way, I can easily see which messages I've sent that do not have any response as there will only be 1 message in the conversation so there won't be a conversation tree.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the advanced find as suggested - that will bring up any where you sent the first message in the conversation and noone replied. But it wont bring up any where you replied to something or forwarded something and haven't had a reply as the conversation will be greater than zero

Answer (score -1):

If you do an Advanced Find on the Sent folder, go to the Advanced tab, and add a Field called Conversation, you can set it's condition to "is empty".

Comment: This will not help, as the Conversation field is set immediately to the value of the subject field when you send a new mail, no matter if it has been replied to or not.