# How to search for unanswered emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I'd like to search Outlook 2013 for emails I sent that never received a reply. How can I do that?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that comes to my mind is to customize message list view:

1. Open the **VIEW** tab on a ribbon.
2. Click the **View Settings** button.
3. Click the **Filter...** button.
4. Open the **SQL** tab.
5. Check **Edit these criteria directly** in the bottom of the tab.
6. Type the following to the **Find items that match these criteria** box:

```
NOT ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003" = 102 OR "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003" = 103)
```

This will filter messages that has not PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED MAPI property set to  NOTEIVERB_REPLYTOSENDER or NOTEIVERB_REPLYTOALL. You can also add [other verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee218425(v=exchg.80).aspx) if required, just list their numerical values using OR as shown above.

You can also create a new Outlook view and select it when needed.

Comment: How to test this? I'm using MS Exchange server. I created this rule under the SQL tab but it was gone after I navigated to another mail folder

Comment: How can I do it in Outlook Web?

Answer (score 1):

These steps got me a lot closer. Rules are pretty limited, but perhaps a guru could create some type of way to be aware of any that are considered too slow, for whatever definition you have of that.

1. Open Outlook and click in the Search box towards top right.
2. Now click ‘Advanced’.
3. In the Search criteria, Select ‘Read Status’ from the drop down menu.
4. Now select ‘Is Not’ in the middle box and then select ‘Replied To'.
5. It will pull up a list of all the unreplied emails.
6. Now click on ‘Save search’ in the Ribbon, type a Name and hit the Enter key.

It will create a Folder in the ‘Smart Folders’ in the left Navigation Pane, the next time if you want to pull up the emails which have been Unreplied, you can click on the Folder that we created under Smart Folders.

Comment: I am unable to follow these steps. The `Replied to` filter is neither available in Outlook web not in Outlook desktop.