# Outlook - Showing ONLY threaded messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm trying to pull email data from outlook (2016) for a report. 
The data I need is threaded emails only (conversations). I need the original message, the reply message and any other correspondence in line with the thread. I don't need messages that are stand-alone messages/messages with no reply (we receive a good bit of email that does not require a reply)

So far for other reports, I've used the Advanced Search to pull the data I need, but I can't find anything to sort threaded messages only.

A secondary thought was to use the search bar to show the specific date range I want to see, then have the messages be grouped by conversations...unfortunately, ALL conversation groups will not stay expanded at one time for me to copy and then paste into Excel (if you attempt to copy the collapsed thread, it only copies the most recent email)

Any suggestions or advice to help me achieve the desired results would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/970558/how-to-search-for-unanswered-emails